# Determine rasters particular area's within ranges using python

Tags: arcpy, raster, spatial-analyst

My directions:

Create a script that determines what areas meet the following
conditions:

- Moderate slope — between 5 and 20 degrees
- Southerly aspect — between 150 and 270 degrees
- Forested — land cover types of 41, 42, or 43

Be sure to use the map algebra expressions of the arcpy.sa module.

I'm getting a final raster image with 3 colors on it when it should only be two...either you are in range of the above constraints or not.

```
#import arcpy
import arcpy
#set env
from arcpy import env
#set workspace
env.workspace = "D:/UW/Winter_2016/501/w5_more_arcpy8_9_10/ex9/"
from arcpy.sa import *

try:

    if arcpy.CheckExtension("spatial")== "Available":
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
#set elevation raster
        elevraster = arcpy.Raster("elevation")

        sloper = Slope(elevraster)
#Moderate slope — between 5 and 20 degrees
        idealslope = sloper < 20
        idealslope_lower = sloper > 5

        slopeFinal = idealslope - idealslope_lower

        slopeFinal.save("slopeFinal")

#Southerly aspect — between 150 and 270 degrees
        sAspect = Aspect(elevraster)
        s = sAspect > 150
        n = sAspect < 270

        sAspectFinal = n - s

        sAspectFinal.save("sAspectFinal")
#Forested — land cover types of 41, 42, or 43
#forestCover = arcpy.Raster("landcover.tif")

        forestCover = RemapValue([[41,1], [42,2], [43,3]])
        outreclass = Reclassify("D:/UW/Winter_2016/501/w5_more_arcpy8_9_10/ex9/landcover.tif", "VALUE", forestCover, "NODATA")
        outreclass.save("forestReclass")

        properArea = (outreclass & sAspectFinal & slopeFinal)
        properArea.save("properArea") 

        arcpy.CheckInExtension("spatial")

finally:
    print "I'm done"
```

Suggestions? I'm sure there is a much better way to do this but I'm so new just trying to do it step by step, so I can understand the larger thinking process in writing python.

Comment: not real sure how to set up the if statement here...

Answer (score 4):

just a quick answer, but I see that you combine your aspect conditions using minus, which mean that you will end up with 3 values (-1, 0 and 1). You should instead multiply those results if you want to find layers that satisfy both conditions. Note that you can also use "and" operator in this case.

```
sAspectFinal = n * s
slopeFinal = idealslope * idealslope_lower

sAspectFinal = (sAspect > 150) and (sAspect < 270)
```

also you remap with 3 different values, if I understand well what you need you should set the same value.

```
forestCover = RemapValue([[41,1], [42,1], [43,1]])
```

or

```
outreclass = (forestRaster > 40) and (forestRaster < 44)
```

final notice, & is a bitwise operator. It is safer to use "and" (works with 0/1 rasters)

Comment: changing & to and, gets this error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 40, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of a raster is ambiguous. Invalid use of raster with Boolean operator or function. Check the use of parentheses where applicable.

Comment: pretty sure it is the outreclass since it has 3 values, it needs to be combined into one

Comment: and will not work if you do not have a binary raster, so if you did not change your outreclass this explains the error message. & compare bit by bit, e.g. 3 is interpreted as 11 and 1 is interpreted as 1, so the results exists (in this case, 1)

Comment: I'll be honest that confuses me...

Comment: sorry if unclear, wikipedia probably does a better job than me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: note that if all rasters only have 0 or 1 values, "&" and "and" give the same same result

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with for an answer based on feedback above and google..

```
#import arcpy
import arcpy
#set env
from arcpy import env
#set workspace
env.workspace = "D:/UW/Winter_2016/501/w5_more_arcpy8_9_10/ex9/"
from arcpy.sa import *

try:

    if arcpy.CheckExtension("spatial")== "Available":
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
#set elevation  and forest cover raster files
        elevraster = arcpy.Raster("elevation")
        forestCoverTif = arcpy.Raster("D:/UW/Winter_2016/501/w5_more_arcpy8_9_10/ex9/landcover.tif")

        sloper = Slope(elevraster)
#Moderate slope — between 5 and 20 degrees
        idealslope = sloper < 20
        idealslope_lower = sloper > 5

        slopeFinal = idealslope * idealslope_lower



#Southerly aspect — between 150 and 270 degrees
        sAspect = Aspect(elevraster)
        s = sAspect > 150
        n = sAspect < 270

        sAspectFinal = n * s


#Forested — land cover types of 41, 42, or 43
#forestCover = arcpy.Raster("landcover.tif")

        outlandCover = ((forestCoverTif == 41) | (forestCoverTif == 42) | (forestCoverTif == 43))

#need to make one forest cover class for these three values

        properArea = (outlandCover & sAspectFinal & slopeFinal)
        properArea.save("properArea") 

        arcpy.CheckInExtension("spatial")

finally:
    print "I'm done running the script."
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Exercise09"
if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
elev = arcpy.Raster("elevation")
lc = arcpy.Raster("landcover.tif")
slope = Slope(elev)
aspect = Aspect(elev)
goodslope = ((slope > 5) & (slope < 20))
goodaspect = ((aspect > 150) & (aspect < 270))
goodland = ((lc == 41) | (lc == 42) | (lc ==43))
outraster = (goodslope & goodaspect & goodland)
outraster.save("C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Exercise09/Results/final")
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```